# Set array within one object equal to array in another object?

Tags: c++, arrays, class

Say I have a class called A:

```
class A{
private:
    int myarray[3];
    int other;
public:
    void setarray(int cell_one, int cell_two, int cell_three);
    // ^ Sets values passed to function to elements in myarray 
}
```

And two A objects in my main:

```
int main(){
A a_one;
A a_two;

a_one.setarray(5,3,6);

}
```

Is there a way to copy the array in a_one to the array in a_two, without setting the other values equal?

Comment: Anything wrong with `a_two = a_one;`?

Comment: What if there are other data members I dont want to set equal to each other, just the arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead. Then you can implement the copying through simple assignment.

For example you could create a function which returns a (possible `const`) reference to the array, and assign using these functions. Perhaps something like

```
struct A
{
    std::array<int, 3> a;
    // Other member variables...

    std::array<int, 3> const& get_array() const
    {
        return a;
    }

    std::array<int, 3>& get_array()
    {
        return a;
    }
};

// ...

a_one.get_array() = a_two.get_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's the obvious way -- make a method that you can call to do that:

```
public:
   void setArrayFromA(const A & him)
   {
      for (int i=0; i<3; i++) myarray[i] = him.myarray[i];
   }
```

[...]

```
a_one.setArrayFromA(a_two);
```

Answer (score 0):

Class definition :

```
class A{
private:
 std::array<int,3> myarray;
 int other;
public:
 void setarray(int cell_one, int cell_two, int cell_three);
 // ^ Sets values passed to function to elements in myarray 
}
```

Then you can set it as :

```
int main(){
 A a_one;
 A a_two;

 a_one.setarray(5,3,6);
 a_two.myarray = a_one.myarray;    
}
```